# Listing all available system fonts in a Choice Box

Tags: java, javafx-8

I have a scene with a choice box. the aim is to get all available system fonts to display in the choice box, I kinda feel I'm on the right path as so far I have managed to get 1 to display in the choice box, but why just the 1?

here is the code -

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ChoiceBox;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;

public class ChoiceBoxFonts extends Application
{
   ObservableList<String> fontType;
   ChoiceBox<String> fonts;

    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) 
    {
        Pane root = new Pane();

        Font.getFamilies().stream().forEach(i ->{
            fontType =
                      FXCollections.observableArrayList(i 
                              );
        });

        // New choicebox with observable arraylist fontType
        fonts =  new ChoiceBox<String> (fontType);

        //SingleSelectionModel<String> selMod = fonts.getSelectionModel();

        root.getChildren().add(fonts);
        Scene scene = new Scene(root,200,200);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();

    }
}
```

The goal of the experiment is to be able to select a font from the choice box and change the font of a text object with that selection.

Also, is there a better UI to be able to do such a thing? If there are a bucket load of fonts, that choice box is going to be very long!

Comment: "for each element of `Font.getFamilies()`, set `fontType` to a list containing just that element". After you do all that, you will have a list containing only the last element.

Comment: HI, @James_D, thats what I've done though? - "for each element of Font.getFamilies()"  with this line of code - 'Font.getFamilies().stream().forEach(i ->{ 
fontType =
                      FXCollections.observableArrayList(i 
                              );'

Comment: apologies for the formatting of these comments..

Comment: Well, yes, that's exactly what you're doing. That's kind of my point. First, set `fontType` to be a list containing only the first element. Second, set `fontType` to be a list containing only the second element. Third, set `fontType` to be a list containing only the thrid element... So after you do all that, what do you expect `fontType` to be?

Comment: sorry, misunderstanding!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need

```
fontType = FXCollections.observableArrayList(Font.getFamilies());
```

instead of the iteration you have.

> If there are a bucket load of fonts, that choice box is going to be very long!

I would probably consider a [`ListView`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

Comment: thats great, I'll look into it. Thanks